# Divide input into several maps

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra

I have a question. Is it possible to divide our input of a mapreduce program to process with several map functions? I mean can we assign a specific range of input to each map function?

Comment: Of course, it's a distributed algorithm? If you want to control the number of maps you can play around with the split size, you can split your input in different files,... Can you be a little more specific as to what you are trying to do?

Comment: thanks for your reply.. Yes, My input is from cassandra. for example I want map1 read data from row 1 to 1000, map2 read data from row 1000 to 2000 and so on. this way, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use [`MultipleInputs`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/MultipleInputs.html#addInputPath%28org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class%29). Particularly, use `addInputPath` function that has the parameter to pass in a mapper class.

Here is an example:

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(thejob, new Path(path1), TextInputFormat.class, Mapper1.class);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(thejob, new Path(path2), TextInputFormat.class, Mapper2.class);
...
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(thejob, new Path(pathN), TextInputFormat.class, MapperN.class);
```

This will make it so `Mapper1` is run against `path1`, and `Mapper2` is run against `path2`, etc.

Note that the limitation here is that your division of input needs to be done through files... not input splits or anything like that. The easiest way to do this is to have one folder of data per mapper.